# PHP replace wildcards (%s, %d) in string with vars

Tags: php

I have translate function `t($var);`

```
function t($word) {
    return $this->words[$word];
}
```

where `$this->words` is array

```
$this->words = array(
    'word1' => 'word',
    'word2' => 'something'
);
```

I am using functions as `<?php echo t('word1'); ?>`
and output is : `word`

**My goal** is to use wildcards **%s**, **%d**, **%f** to replace them with variables.

Example:

```
$this->words = array(
    'word1' => 'word',
    'word2' => 'something',
    'sentence' => 'Hello, my name is %s. I am %d years old.'
);
```

Then parse variables into `t()` function.

```
<?php echo t('sentence', array('Mike', 99));
```

So output will be: `Hello, my name is Mike. I am 99 years old.`

**My Work so far:**

```
function t($word, $vars = array()) {
    foreach ($vars as $key) {
        if(is_string($key)){
            $this->words[$word] = str_replace ('%s', $key, $this->words[$word]);
        }
        if(is_int($key)) {
            $this->words[$word] = str_replace ('%d', $key, $this->words[$word]);
        }
        if(is_float($key)){
            $this->words[$word] = str_replace ('%f', $key, $this->words[$word]);
        }
    }
    return $this->words[$word];
}
```

But this function doesn't work with more than one of each type of variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen people recommend using `sprintf` but personally I'd recommend using `vsprintf`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

```
function t($word, $vars = array()) {
  return vsprintf($this->words[$word], $vars);
}
```

This allows you to pass in an array of variables instead of passing them in as separate parameters.

Generally translate functions will first check for a translation and if not found just return the lookup key.

```
function t($word, $vars = array()) {
  return isset($this->words[$word]) ? vsprintf($this->words[$word], $vars) : $word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the t function like below :

```
function t($array)
{
    return sprintf($array['sentence'],$array['word1'],$array['word1']);
}
```

Where array is :

```
$array = array(
    'word1' => 'word',
    'word2' => 'something',
    'sentence' => 'Hello, my name is %s. I am %d years old.'
);
```

Call the function :
    echo t($array);

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you're restricted to passing in a predefined number of words (in this case 2).  You could do something dynamic with `eval()` but don't. There's vsprintf which takes an array of values instead as shown in my answer.